# How to insert data to four tables from one view in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I have four domain classes in my Grails based web application (first I've ever made):

```
class Receipt
{
    String title
    Date dateCreated
    static hasMany = [articles: Article]
    static constraints =
    {
        title blank: false, unique: true
    }
}

class Article
{
    String name
    Quantity quantity
    TypeOfArticle typeOfArticle
    static hasOne = [quantity:Quantity, typeOfArticle:TypeOfArticle]
    static constraints =
    {
        quantity unique: true
    }
}

class Quantity
{
    Integer quantity
    Article article
}

class TypeOfArticle
{
    String type
    Article article
}
```

How can I add one Receipt together with all details on one view?
I want to make it look like on this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNVzW.png

I hope you'll be able to help me! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know what is GSP? http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#gsp

Comment: See the grails documentation for the standard examples. Basic controllers and services should help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look up Command Objects.  It looks like you are trying to have someone enter data into one form that spans multiple classes.  You can create a Command Object that has fields from all four classes.  You use that object for the gsp fields, then capture in the controller method and validate the data; then create your actual Receipt, Article, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameter in your controller action,In action you can simply write **object.propertyName=params.propertyName** and after getting all parameters you can simply store it by calling **object.save()**. you can do the same process for all four tables..